# How to prevent Dataframe.to_dict() to generate timestamps

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, timestamp

I am trying to use the python Dataframe to_dict() method without generating timestamps.
My problem: I have a dataframe with cells containing dates such as this: "2019-06-01". When I call the dataframe method "to-dict()" to generate a dictionnary, it converts the datevalue into something like: "Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00')".
This is not what I would like. I would just like it to return a simple string such as: "2019-06-01"
Is it possible with optional parameters ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert those columns to object type with `.astype(str)` before calling `to_dict()`.